# How to deal with DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am learning about writing custom JavaScript for my Odoo 10 addons.

I've written the following piece of code:

```
odoo.define('ioio.io', function(require) {
  'use strict'

  const e = $('div.o_sub_menu_footer')
  console.log('--testing--'.repeat(7))
  console.log(e)

  // the "Powered by Odoo" down the secondary menu
  e.remove()
})
```

The code is well loaded and I can see my testing string in the console.
However when this code is being loaded before the target `div`, so `e` empty/not yet filled and thus its content is not removed.
Doing it manually from the console works.

My question is what is the right way to do that? And how to know exactly when the code gets executed?

Comment: TIL `String.repeat(n)`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- put your html code before the script tag in your file
- use jQuery [$(document).ready(...)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/);

Answer (score 1):

Place your script at the bottom of the `<body>` tag to make sure the DOM renders before trying to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Odoo specific question, so you should use the Odoo standard way, which is via its `base` JS class. That class contains a `ready()` method which does exactly what you need.

In your case, to use that function, you need to require the class first. Then you can use `ready()`.

Updating your code, it should look like this:

```
odoo.define('ioio.io', function(require) {
  'use strict'

  // require base class
  var base = require('web_editor.base');

  //use its ready method
  base.ready().done(function () {

  // put all the code you want to get loaded 
  // once the DOM is loaded within this block

  const e = $('div.o_sub_menu_footer')
  console.log('--testing--'.repeat(7))
  console.log(e)

  // the "Powered by Odoo" down the secondary menu
  e.remove()
  });
})
```

While your accepted answer leads to the same outcome, you might want to update it to this one since this is the Odoo way. It's generally advised to work within the Odoo framework as much as possible and customise only if really needed. (Though it can be tough to learn what features Odoo already provides because of its poor documentation.)